# solana blocktimestamp && block status

Tags: debug

https://docs.solana.com/implemented-proposals/validator-timestamp-oracle
The same implementation can provide a timestamp estimate for a not-yet-rooted block. However, because the most recent timestamped slot may or may not be rooted yet, this timestamp would be unstable (potentially failing requirement 1). Initial implementation will target rooted blocks, but if there is a use case for recent-block timestamping, it will be trivial to add the RPC apis in the future.
I have 2 questions below

1）is rooted blocks means finality block？

2）is there any RCP APIS can get recent-block timestamp？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, "rooted" means "final": https://docs.solana.com/terminology#root
2. To get the timestamp on a block, you can use the `getBlockTime` RPC endpoint, providing the slot number: https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getblocktime, and you can get the current slot with `getSlot` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getslot

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my second question was about whether there is a way to obtain the timestamp of a block in the processed state. The normal progression of block states is processed -> confirmed -> final. Is there an API available to retrieve the time when a block reaches the processed state, which should be earlier than the final state? Just like this sentence mentions, "Initial implementation will target rooted blocks, but if there is a use case for recent-block timestamping, it will be trivial to add the RPC apis in the future."

Comment: Ah I see, the term "recent-block" doesn't seem to be a common term anywhere, so I would avoid using it. The answer to your question is "no" because "processed" blocks are not available in the blockstore