# solana blocktimestamp && block status V2.0

Tags: debug

question before
[solana blocktimestamp && block status](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9381/solana-blocktimestamp-block-status/9472?noredirect=1#comment7587_9472)
If I cannot obtain the timestamp of a block in the "processed" state through the API, is it possible to retrieve it through logs? What I mean is, when the client receives a new block and that block enters the "processed" state, will the client generate log notifications? If so, I can monitor the log outputs and use the log's local timestamp as the time when the block enters the "processed" state